C# Digital Ocean Spaces Error making request with Error Code Forbidden and Http Status Code Forbidden. No further error information was return
I’m using Digital Ocean Spaces but I can’t upload images correctly from my Dotnet Web Api application using AWS.SDK I get error:

Error making request with Error Code Forbidden and Http Status Code Forbidden. No further error information was return.

This is my code, also tried with the commented code same error:
        public async Task<bool> AddUserImage(ImageCreateDTO imageCreateDto)
        {
            try
            {
                var credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(_storageOptions.Value.AccessKey, _storageOptions.Value.SecretKey);

                AmazonS3Config config = new()
                {
                    ServiceURL = _storageOptions.Value.ServiceUrl,
                };

                AmazonS3Client s3Client = new(
                        _storageOptions.Value.AccessKey,
                        _storageOptions.Value.SecretKey,
                        config
                        );
                using var stream = imageCreateDto.File.OpenReadStream();

                TransferUtility fileTransferUtility = new(s3Client);

                TransferUtilityUploadRequest fileTransferUtilityRequest = new()
                {
                    BucketName = $"joinorcreate/{_storageOptions.Value.UserImages}",
                    StorageClass = S3StorageClass.Standard,
                    PartSize = imageCreateDto.File.Length,
                    Key = imageCreateDto.FileName,
                    CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicRead,
                    InputStream = stream
                };

                // Add the x-amz-acl header
                fileTransferUtilityRequest.Headers["x-amz-acl"] = "public-read";

                await fileTransferUtility.UploadAsync(fileTransferUtilityRequest);

                // PutObjectRequest request = new()
                // {
                //     BucketName = $"joinorcreate/{_storageOptions.Value.UserImages}",
                //     Key = imageCreateDto.FileName,
                //     InputStream = stream,
                //     ContentType = imageCreateDto.File.ContentType,
                //     CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicRead,
                //     StorageClass = S3StorageClass.Standard,

                // };


                // await s3Client.PutObjectAsync(request);

                return true;
            }
            catch (AmazonS3Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                return false;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                return false;
            }
        }

Please can you help me? Also I don’t want the images to have permission private but public when added by default, when the code above works?
I’ve tried everything, looked at other issues like:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/uploading-file-to-do-spaces-using-aws-sdk-net-net-core
I was expecting the image to be uploaded successfully!

Downgrading the Amazon S3 SDK nuget package to 3.7.102 fixed the issue for me.
